# Custom command button from grid isn't updating partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, grid, kendo-ui, partial-views

I have created a sample project to illustrate my problem

**Index.cshtml :**

```html
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model IEnumerable<KendoUIMvcApplication3.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickView(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ViewDetails",
            data: { productId: dataItem.Id }
        });
    }
</script>
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("RoleGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width("30%");
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
                  columns.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                          command.Destroy();
                          command.Custom("View").Click("clickView");
                      }).Width(250);
              })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add"))
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px" })
</div>

@{ Html.RenderAction("ViewDetails", "Home", new { productId = 0 });}
```

**ViewDetails action in my HomeController :**

```cs
public ActionResult ViewDetails(int productId)
{
    Detail model;
    if (productId == 0)
    {
        model = new Detail
            {
                Price = "zero",
                Origin = "zero"
            };
    } else {
        model = new Detail
            {
                Price = productId.ToString(),
                Origin = productId.ToString()
            };
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**ViewDetails.cshtml :**

```
@model KendoUIMvcApplication3.Models.Detail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewDetails";
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Origin)
```

Everything runs fine.

Clicking the custom "View" button fires off the javascript, which makes an ajax call to my `ViewDetails` action. The `productId` value is passed correctly, however, the `return(model)` of my `ViewDetails` action doesn't update my view page at all.

Should I not be using `RenderAction` in my index.cshtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display that Partial view under the Grid when any of the buttons is clicked you should use the **success** callback function of the $.ajax.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model IEnumerable<KendoUIMvcApplication3.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickView(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ViewDetails",
            data: { productId: dataItem.Id },
            success:function(response){
                $('#viewDetails').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("RoleGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width("30%");
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
                  columns.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                          command.Destroy();
                          command.Custom("View").Click("clickView");
                      }).Width(250);
              })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add"))
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px" })
</div>

<div id="viewDetails"></div>
```